# RTL-SDR with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: pi-2, television-tuner

Does anyone know of a way to use a RTL-SDR USB dongle with the Pi 2 B?

A RTL-SDR is a DVB-T+FM+DAB USB dongle designed to be a TV tuner for a Laptop PC but used on a PC with a program such as SDRSharp.

My project is to use the Pi to free up the shack PC for other things.

Comment: As one ham to another the short answer is yes, take a look at these https://learn.adafruit.com/freq-show-raspberry-pi-rtl-sdr-scanner/usage https://learn.adafruit.com/freq-show-raspberry-pi-rtl-sdr-scanner/overview also do a search for sdr and magpi (which is the official Raspberry Pi foundation's magazine). I am not sure what  SDRSharp is or if it is available for the Pi, but you are likely to find at least one similar package.

Comment: Thanks for that I shall investigate those links. SDRSharp is one of many programs which interface and control/decode the I & Q data streams form the RTL-SDR USB TV receivers sticks, $10 on fleebay)